# Sql - FOR XML Path query issue

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, for-xml-path

I have query written as below (sample).

```
Select 'Somthing' as Title,
       'Some notes' as Notes,
        (Select Path1
        From (Select 'One' Path1
              union
              Select 'Two' Path1
              union
              Select 'Three' Path1) T        
         FOR XML PATH('Image'),ROOT('Images'), ELEMENTS, TYPE),

         'Other value' as Value

FOR XML PATH('ItemRow'),TYPE,ELEMENTS
```

Which outputs below xml

```
<ItemRow>
  <Title>Somthing</Title>
  <Notes>Some notes</Notes>
  <Images>
    <Image>
      <Path1>One</Path1>
    </Image>
    <Image>
      <Path1>Two</Path1>
    </Image>
    <Image>
      <Path1>Three</Path1>
    </Image>
  </Images>
  <Value>Other value</Value>
</ItemRow>
```

I am trying to put Notes and Images in to parent node, so it should appear as below

```
<ItemRow>
  <Title>Somthing</Title>
  <SomeParentNode>
    <Notes>Some notes</Notes>
    <Images>
      <Image>
        <Path1>One</Path1>
      </Image>
      <Image>
        <Path1>Two</Path1>
      </Image>
      <Image>
        <Path1>Three</Path1>
      </Image>
    </Images>
  </SomeParentNode>
  <Value>Other value</Value>
</ItemRow>
```

It this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `SomeParentNode` like this:

```
Select 'Somthing' as Title,
       'Some notes' as 'SomeParentNode/Notes', -- here
        (Select Path1 
        From (Select 'One' Path1
              union
              Select 'Two' Path1
              union
              Select 'Three' Path1) T        
         FOR XML PATH('Image'),ROOT('Images'), ELEMENTS, TYPE) AS 'SomeParentNode', -- and here

         'Other value' as [Value]

FOR XML PATH('ItemRow'),TYPE,ELEMENTS
```

Output:

```
<ItemRow>
  <Title>Somthing</Title>
  <SomeParentNode>
    <Notes>Some notes</Notes>
    <Images>
      <Image>
        <Path1>One</Path1>
      </Image>
      <Image>
        <Path1>Two</Path1>
      </Image>
      <Image>
        <Path1>Three</Path1>
      </Image>
    </Images>
  </SomeParentNode>
  <Value>Other value</Value>
</ItemRow>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The long way, using subqueries to place the element in the proper path:

```sql
SELECT
    'Something' AS Title,
    (
        SELECT
            'Some Notes' AS Notes,
            (
                SELECT
                    Path1
                FROM    
                    (VALUES('One'),('Two'),('Three')) AS T(Path1)
                FOR 
                    XML PATH('Image'), TYPE
            )
        FOR 
            XML PATH('Images'), TYPE
    ),
    'Other value' as Value
FOR
    XML PATH('ItemRow')
```

---

2. The short way, in which you select the element in the proper place by adding the root element name in the field name

```sql
SELECT
    'Something' AS Title,
    'Some Notes' AS [Images/Notes],
    (
        SELECT
            Path1
        FROM    
            (VALUES('One'),('Two'),('Three')) AS T(Path1)
        FOR 
            XML PATH('Image'), TYPE
    ) AS [Images],
    'Other value' as Value
FOR
    XML PATH('ItemRow')
```

---

Both result in:

```
<ItemRow>
  <Title>Something</Title>
  <Images>
    <Notes>Some Notes</Notes>
    <Image>
      <Path1>One</Path1>
    </Image>
    <Image>
      <Path1>Two</Path1>
    </Image>
    <Image>
      <Path1>Three</Path1>
    </Image>
  </Images>
  <Value>Other value</Value>
</ItemRow>
```